# Comparison function returning incorrect results with overloaded operator

Tags: c++, templates

I am not quite sure where my error is, also I am very new to programming and I know I am breaking a lot of standardization rules. I am learning. The user inputs two integers and it compares them, it always reports that the first integer entered is greater, even when it shouldn't. I want to say it is something wrong with my `getlength` method, but at this point I am not too sure.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>




using namespace std;

template <class T>

//Function to find larger value a = first number, b = second number
T findLargerValue(T a, T b) {

    return (a>b ? a:b);
}

//Class trip

template <class T>
class Trip {


public: 
     Trip<T>::Trip();

    Trip(T a){

         length = a;

    }

    T operator>(Trip yourTrip);


    T getLength() {

        return length;
    }

private:
    T length;

};

// Template function to carry into 

/** This is where I seem to be losing my logic, I am trying to push larger of the two objects to the screen but it is only  displaying the first user input This is supposed to take in the two bojects created and measure the lengths.**/

template<class T> 
T Trip<T>::operator>(Trip yourTrip) {
    if (length > yourTrip.getLength()) {

        return length;
    }

    else{
        return yourTrip.getLength();
    }
}

template<class T>
Trip<T>::Trip()
{

}



int main()
{

    // input for integer values

    int num1 , num2 ;

    cout << "Enter integer value 1: ";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Enter integer value 2: ";
    cin >> num2;



    //display message of first two numbers
    cout <<"Frist Number was: " << num1 << " Second Number was: " << num2 << "\nThe Larger number of the two is "
        <<  findLargerValue(num1, num2) << endl << endl;


    //input for double values

    double num3, num4;

    cout << "Enter double value 1: ";
    cin >> num3;

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Enter double value 2: ";
    cin >> num4;

    //display mesasge of second two numbers
    cout << "Frist Number was: " << num3 << " Second Number was: " << num4 << "\nThe Larger number of the two is "
         << findLargerValue(num3, num4) << endl << endl;

    // Display message for Trip function/objects 

    int fTlength, sTlength;
    cout << "How many miles was your first trip: ";
    cin >> fTlength;

    Trip<int> fTrip(fTlength);

    cout << endl;

    cout << "How many miles was your second trip: ";
    cin >> sTlength;

    Trip<int> sTrip(sTlength);

    Trip<int> tripLonger;
    tripLonger = findLargerValue(fTrip, sTrip);

    cout << "First trip in miles: " << fTlength << endl << "Second Trip in miles: " << sTlength << endl;



    cout << "The longest trip was " << tripLonger.getLength() << " miles." << endl;



    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tripLonger = findLargerValue(fTrip, sTrip);` this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overloaded the `operator >` incorrectly. It should return `true` of `false`, but it returns (in this case) an integral value. It should look like this:

```
template<class T> 
bool Trip<T>::operator>(const Trip& yourTrip)
{
    return length > yourTrip.length;
}
```

Comparison operators should indicate whether or not the comparison is true. In your case, it was returning either `length` or `yourTrip.length`. This is a problem when `findLargerValue` calls `operator >` for the two objects. It checks if the result was true, and because any integer that isn't `0` is `true`, it was almost always returning the first object. If you had entered a negative number and a `0`, it would have returned the second object.

Comment: Thank you! As soon as you pointed that out took me 5 minutes to fix the issue!